# how to solve a difference equation using Z transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab, difference-equations

I'm trying to find the impulse response of a filter expressed by a difference equation as below:

y[n] - y[n-1] + 0.9*y[n-2] = x[n] - x[n-2]

I want to use Z-transform in order to solve he equation. I use this code in Matlab:

```
syms y(n) z  
eq = y(n) - y(n - 1) - 0.9*y(n - 2) - impulse_me(n) + impulse_me(n - 2);
Zeq = ztrans(eq, n, z);
```

and I have declared impulse_me function as below:

```
function [ y ] = impulse_me( n )
    y = (n==0);
    end
```

but when I run the code the result is:

```
Zeq =

ztrans(y(n) - (9*y(n - 2))/10 - y(n - 1) - 2 == y(n) - (9*y(n - 2))/10 - y(n - 1), n, z)
```

can anybody help me with the problem?